# What's the meaning of ninja in a technological article?

Tags: vocabulary, japanese

I always saw some articles which use `ninja` to refer to a person. What does it mean in a technological article?

> [True path to become a JavaScript Ninja](https://medium.com/dev-blogs/true-path-to-become-a-javascript-ninja-4c34224c633)

I guess maybe it means master or guru. If that's true, why not just use `guru` instead?

Comment: Tech terms change like fashion. Guru used to be popular, but would now sound stale and uncool.

Answer (score 3):

***[Ninja](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ninja)***  is a term also used in a figurative sense:

> a person who is expert or highly skilled in a specified field or activity (often used attributively):
>
> - marketing ninjas; ninja gamers.

(Dictionary.com)

in computing, for instance:

> ***[data ninja](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29222/data-ninja)***  is a person who reviews large quantities of data and analyzes, organizes and moves it in such a way that it improves overall data retrieval processes, thus allowing the data to reach end users much more quickly.
>
> A data ninja is similar to a data analyst, but besides analyzing data at rest, this person also optimizes the data access and transfer process.

(Techopedia)